# Web Api in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, web

First of all, I created an ASP.NET application and I added a WebApi controller to the project. Several methods get added that include get, post, and delete. I launched the project and accessed the wep api get method through

```
http://localhost:<portnumber>/api/employees
```

This works find and I'm able to download the default values that vs generates. My problems occurs when I try to return in the get method, data from my data base: for instance take a look at this code snippet:

```
    // GET api/employees
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Get()
    {
        return employeeRepo.Employees;
    }
```

When I launch the application and type this url

```
http://localhost:<portnumber>/api/employees
```

the browser tells me that I can't download the file.

Can someone please tell me what am doing wrong? For some reason its not allowing me to get the data, it only works if I use an in memory list or the defaults values of visual studio.

Comment: What happens in debugger? Is list really pulled from db? You could also examine the http request from the browser and see if there is anything strange there.

Comment: @korhner does the Web api need to be from the entity framework template? since I'm using the entity framework as the orm for my application

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking. Is Web Api a separate project? If yes, than you should reference Entity Framework and also add connection strings in Web.config file.

Comment: for right no, my web api is not in a separate project

Comment: What browser are you using?  Is this simply a problem in that a Json response from the WebAPI can't be displayed in the browser?

Comment: Try forcing the enumeration of your results. return employeeRepo.Employees.ToList(); If you're using Entity Framework with lazy loading, just returning the enumerable won't actually get the data.

Comment: I'm using Internet explorer, it's just strange that the web api works great with an in memory list but not with my database

Comment: HEY GUYS just got an error message on firefox stating that Type 'JustWorks.WebUI.Controllers.Apis.Default2Controller' does not have a default constructor

Comment: Okay guys well @Brendan Green got me in the right track of changing browsers, when I did saw an error message and was able to resolve the issue. but for some reason my DI ninject is not working in the web api. Any solutions:

Comment: Show the code you're using to register the controllers and set the dependency resolver.